# Can I reorder parameters via refactoring or regex?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I've written a lot of code using a method I created with the following signature:

```
public void DrawString(int x, int y, string str, 
    TextAlignment align, Color col) { ... }
```

I regret ordering the parameters like that, and want to change the signature to this:

```
public void DrawString(int x, int y, string str, 
    Color col, TextAlignment align) { ... }
```

Presently I'm using both signatures (I made an overload that passes the prior signature to the latter), but I want to completely remove the prior signature.

Reordering parameters, I believe, can have side-effects, but in my particular case it won't. Although Visual Studio 2013 seems to have a [Reorder Parameters Refactoring (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ss5z206%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) feature, it must not be for Express users, since nowhere have I seen a "Reorder Parameters" option.

Is there a way to change this parameter order without updating hundreds of method calls manually?

Comment: Perhaps downloading an evaluation version of vs premium?

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring is the only reasonable solution, I think. And you have plenty of choices there. The most obvious: just switch input parameters manually. Right after that, during compilation, you'll get a list of errors in all places where you call `DrawString`. So just fix all errors manually. 
Another option: install some tool which provides extended refactoring functionality like ReSharper/CodeRush/JustCode.
Another option (which you already use) is overloading:

```
 public void DrawString(int x, int y, string str, Color col, TextAlignment align)
 {
     DrawString(x, y, str, align, col);
 }
```

Then mark original `DrawString` as `[Obsolete]` and use only overloaded method in future. But I wouldn't go this way. Code will become pretty unclear.
If you're interested in my personal opinion, then I'd choose 2nd way (it'd be bright idea to use some tool which helps you with routine tasks).